# Unity material.color.a code is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, camera, renderer

```
 void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("tree"))
    {
        Color color = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        color.a = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

If an object with a "tree" tag enters the camera's trigger, I want the opacity of that object to be 0.5. But didn't worked. How can i fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the other two answers are technically correct, you are most likely missing a very important step to allow for the changing of the alpha of a `Material`. I'll take a guess and assume you generated a new `Material` in the Editor by using the `Asset Creation Menu`. By default, the `Material` [`RenderMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderMode.html) is set to `Opaque`.

To allow for changes of the `Material` color's alpha, you will need to set the `RenderMode` either to `Transparent` or `Fade`. If you are working with a custom shader, you will need to alter the code to format to one of the mentioned `RenderTypes`. If you need help modifying your shader, that would best be answered in a new question.

For clarity, here is a gif of what the confusion might be:

[image: Example]

Edit: For completeness, here is a full script that will toggle the `RenderMode` of your material at runtime if you do not wish to change it at compile time.

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class MaterialUtils
{
    public enum BlendMode
    {
        Opaque,
        Cutout,
        Fade,
        Transparent
    }

    public static void SetupBlendMode(Material material, BlendMode blendMode)
    {
        switch (blendMode)
        {
            case BlendMode.Transparent:
                material.SetOverrideTag("RenderType", "Transparent");
                material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
                material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
                material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
                material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
                material.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
                material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
                material.renderQueue = (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.RenderQueue.Transparent;
                material.SetFloat("_Mode", 3.0f);
                break;
            case BlendMode.Opaque:
                material.SetOverrideTag("RenderType", "");
                material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.One);
                material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.Zero);
                material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 1);
                material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
                material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
                material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
                material.renderQueue = -1;
                material.SetFloat("_Mode", 0.0f);
                break;
            default:
                Debug.LogWarning("Warning: BlendMode: " + blendMode + " is not yet implemented!");
                break;
        }
    }
}

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MeshRenderer mr = null;
    [SerializeField] private float alphaChange = 0.5f;
    private bool isOpaque = true;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (mr == null)
            mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // store our color struct and change the alpha channel
        Color clr = mr.material.color;
        clr.a = alphaChange;

        // instance our material to alter the rendermode
        Material mat = mr.material;

        // update our render mode to transparent and our color to the new alpha
        MaterialUtils.SetupBlendMode(mat, isOpaque ? MaterialUtils.BlendMode.Transparent : MaterialUtils.BlendMode.Opaque);
        mat.color = clr;

        // apply our material change
        mr.material = mat;

        // toggle our bool
        isOpaque = !isOpaque;
    }
}
```

Your original question does not state whether or not you need to toggle the material back to opaque, but I included it. You can keep the `RenderMode` as `Transparent` and simply change the alpha back to `1.0f` to make it fully opaque again. Again, here's a gif example of the above script in action:

[image: Example 2]

To show that the snippet is working, I place 2 spheres behind the cubes. The snippet is probably a bit overkill for what you need, but if someone else stumbles on the question and needs a more versatile answer here it is!

Comment: So thank you for detailed answer. But I wrote and saved MaterialUtils in a separate script. And I threw the TestScript into the object. Then I ran the game, but when I changed the alphaChange value, the opacity of the object did not change.

Comment: @quasarparadox The current code is set up now for when you click on the object it will change. It is using the function `OnMouseDown`, which only activates if the object has a collider and is not obstructed when clicked. The alpha will also not update live, it updates when it is clicked. I can update the snippet to change the shader on `Start` instead if you'd like. That way the shader will update the alpha on the first frame to transparent.

Comment: @quasarparadox Anytime! I'm nowhere near a senior dev though - just graduated about a year ago so need to learn a lot more. Glad I could help you out though! If this post answered your question, you can close the question by selecting it as the answer by clicking on the check box to the left of the post. It lets others who have this question know there's a verified question. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the exhaustive answer! It helped me too.

Answer (score 3):

`Color` is just a `struct` and basically just a container of values without further functionality. It is not linked to the `Material` it was taken from.

By assigning only

```
color.a = XY;
```

you do nothing yet.

You have to assign it back to the material!

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (!other.CompareTag("tree")) return;

    var material = other.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    var color = material.color;
    color.a = 0.5f;
    
    material.color = color;       
}
```

Comment: I edited the code as you wrote. but still not working

Comment: what does `not working` mean exactly? Does your material support transparency?

Comment: no, my material is already transparent type. I have exactly what you wrote in the code. But not working

Comment: @quasarparadox what does `not working` mean?

Comment: object is not transparent

Comment: @quasarparadox but it should .. unless your material is actually set to opaque. Are you sure it is set to e.g. `Fade` ?

Comment: @quasarparadox so since you accepted the other answer apparently your object was set to opaque and not to transparent ^^

Comment: @derHugo oh my goodness

Answer (score 1):

You're not really setting the color with the code you wrote.

```
Color color = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
color.a = 0.5f;
```

With the first line you take the color from the object and with the second you set the opacity. But you don't assign it back to the object. You can assign the color back to the object and it should work:

```
other.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;
```

Comment: I edited the code as you wrote. but still not working